# I can't get c++ for loop output right

Tags: c++

I'm using this code to find the exchange rate

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double r, c;

    cout<<"Input Exchange Rate: US Dollar to Yen: ";
    cin>>r;
    cout<<"Input cash on hand: ";
    cin>>c;
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
    cout<<"\tUS Dollar\tYen\n";
    for (int u=1; u<=c; u++)
    cout<<'\t'<<u<<'\t'<<u*r<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want my output to appear  first by ones then by tens then by hundreds
but I get is this [image]

Comment: Can you show us what exactly you want it to output?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

To generate output in steps of one until 10, steps of 10 until 100 etc. you can replace your loop

```
for (int u=1; u<=c; u++)
cout<<'\t'<<u<<'\t'<<u*r<<endl;
```

by the following code:

```
int factor = 1;
do
{
    for (int u=1; u < 10; u++)
    {
        int dollars = u * factor;
        if(dollars > c)
            break;
        cout<<'\t'<<dollars <<'\t'<<dollars * r<<endl;
    }
    factor *= 10;
}
while(factor <= c);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve you can try [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) from `<iomanip>` to create "columns".

Also take a look at [std::left or std::right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left)

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
double sum = c * r;
double value = fmod(sum, 10);
std::cout << "Ones: " << value << std::endl;

sum -= value;
value = fmod(sum, 100);
std::cout << "Tens: " << value / 10.0 << std::endl;

sum -= value;
value = fmod(sum, 1000);
std::cout << "Hundreds: " << value / 100.0 << std::endl;
```